# d3 dynamic text loop

Tags: text, d3.js

I have an array called keys `[1:"XXX",2:"YYY"]` and I have 2 svg elements already on the page. I want each element to have one of the array values, but the code below puts both values in each text label. I tried `keys[i]`, but `i` is undefined. How can I accomplish this?

```
svg.selectAll("svg").
data(keys).
enter()
    .append("svg:text")
         .attr("x", width )
         .attr("y", height).
         .attr("dx", -width/2)
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
         .text(function(keys) { return keys;})
         .attr("transform", "translate(0, 18)")
         .attr("class", "yAxis");
```

Answer (score 0):

The text function argument uses the name `keys`. Try with `d` instead:

```
svg.selectAll("svg")
.data(keys)
.enter()
.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", width )
  .attr("y", height).
  .attr("dx", -width/2)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
  .text(function(d) { return d;})
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 18)")
  .attr("class", "yAxis");
```

The argument of the `attr` and `text` methods is a function that takes a data element and use its values to compute the attribute or text value. You are using the value of the global variable `keys`, that has two elements.

Comment: That gives me the same thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a site that allows you to post code. Other users can fork your code, modify it and help you to debug.